# Configure SSL connection for Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to configure SSL-encrypted connections for Oracle through ODBC. I searched on internet and found the similar set of steps for this configuration and the latest configuration files after changes on **server** side is as follows:

**sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS)

SSL_VERSION = 3.1

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = requested

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

SQLNET.CRYPTO_SEED = 'VALIDSEED111'

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER= (AES256, RC4_256, AES192, 3DES168,
AES128, RC4_128, 3DES112, RC4_56, DES, RC4_40, DES40)

WALLET_LOCATION =   (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin)
    )   )

SSL_CIPHER_SUITES= (SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5)
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )   )

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

WALLET_LOCATION =   (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin)
    )   )

LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1531))
    )   )
```

I also restart the listener after updating the listener.ora file by executing the following commands:

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

The latest configuration files after changes on **client** side is as follows:

**sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, NTS)

SSL_VERSION = 3.1

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT= (AES256, RC4_256, AES192, 3DES168,
AES128, RC4_128, 3DES112, RC4_56, DES, RC4_40, DES40)

WALLET_LOCATION =   (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\owm\wallets)
    )   )

SSL_CIPHER_SUITES= (SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5)

ADR_BASE = C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\log
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
ORCL43 =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT = 1531))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
    (SECURITY=
      (SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN="cn=TGL,cn=OracleContext,c=IN,o=PQR")
    )   )
```

**listener.ora**

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))   )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\log
```

When I am trying to connect the Oracle database through through SQL Plus using ‘ORCL43’, I am getting ‘**ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**’.

Please let me know where am I doing wrong.

Please help me with this.

Comment: in tnsnames.ora the port is 1531, is that good?

Comment: and i think you dont need to declare the SSL_CIPHER_SUITES, let oracle to handle it, through the handshake both side will accept the highest chiper suite

Comment: @Thomas, So I need to remove SSL_CIPHER_SUITES from server as well as client side?

Comment: @Thomas what else I need to change? which port I should use for this?

Comment: you should give it a try to remove SSL_CIPHER_SUITES option in sqlnet.ora file, it's a server side file, only the server can control the encryption, the client doesnt. And in PRODUCTION its a payable option to control that and really a deep level thing too

Comment: you need to stay at 1521 port at first

Comment: so the controlling of the secure message sending needs to be done in code level, with using utl_http built-in oracle package

Comment: after you setting up wallet and ACL of course

Comment: read this article: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl

Comment: @Thomas, I edited my question. I am trying to connect the Oracle through SQL plus not any other application. I removed the SSL_CIPHER_SUITES from server and used port 1521, still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I see, and what is the code you are running?

Comment: @Thomas, my application is connecting to Oracle database through DSN and ORCL43 is DSN. So once I am able to connect Oracle database through SQL plus, my application will also be able to connect Oracle database. Please let me if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both listener.ora (server side) and tnsnames.ora (client side) contains same HOST and PORT values. In your case, if both server and client are in different machine (i.e. having different address), use server address in HOST field for both the files.

This should ideally solve the problem you are facing.

Also, as suggested by others in the comment you should remove the cipher suites option from the files or atleast use those which are considered as secure. Also, for enabling SSL, `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER` is not required. This flag is used to configure oracle native network encryption.

Here's some sample file that I am using to enable 2-way SSL(mutual authentication) for oracledb 12c.

**Client side**

tnsnames.ora

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 10.255.255.255)(PORT = 2848))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
    (SECURITY=
    (SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN="cn=localhost,c=IN"))
  )
```

sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, NTS)

SSL_VERSION = 0

SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = Yes

SSL_EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE="SSL" (# not a required option, check the docs for usages. They have explained it nicely)
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\wallet)
    )
  )

ADR_BASE = C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log
```

**Server side**

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\wallet)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 10.255.255.255)(PORT = 2848))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log
```

sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, NTS)

SSL_VERSION = 0

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\wallet)
    )
  )

ADR_BASE = C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log
```